# How to update ShqrePoint Group name?

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, spgroup

hope everything is fine.

I managed to created / delete SharePoint groups  but also add and remove users using HTTP requests.

The problem i'm facing now is ... how can I update the name of a group ??

I did something which is a mix between the group creation and the addition of user but that throws an error "__metadata does not exist in method GetById"

the problem is i can only reference my group from the ID since the name of the group has changed....

Would someone please be able to help me ...?

Thanks a lot in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use js to test the request,after the test is successful,you fill in the value one by one.

This code works well:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){
$("#btnClick").click(function(){
var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/sitegroups/getbyId(23)";
$.ajax({
url: requestUri,
type: "POST",
data:JSON.stringify({'__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Group' }, 'Title':'testing'}),
headers: {
"content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
"X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE",
"X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
},
success: onSuccess,
error: onError
});
function onSuccess(data) {
alert('Group description updated successfully');
}
function onError(error) {
alert(JSON.stringify(error));
}
});
});
</script>
<input type="button" id="btnClick" value="Update SharePoint Group Details"/>
```

Then you could find you need to add `"X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE"` in header.

Comment: Hi Amos_MSFT, here, you'd like me to add some code on my page right ? The problem is i'm not authorized to do it. The team in charge of O365 deactivated all script webparts and they do not allow custom code.  Do you mean  i should use Method "merge" in my HTTP action in Power Automate and leave the rest untouched ? (the problem is there is no "Merge" in the action but i guess i should use Patch instead)

Comment: I mean you could do a test before you add value in Flow.js code is better than flow for debugging.As I test,set "X-HTTP-Method":"Patch" in headers reports error.

Comment: ok ok... sorry i answer you between meetings :-P I'm sorry but i just start with adding code to flow and playing with HTTP requests so i try to understand . would you please be able to tell me where i should add the code ? ...really sorry :-(

Comment: I just recommend doing this when conditions permit.You could try to use my suggestion in your flow.

Comment: me again sorry for the delay. ok but where should i put the code in the flow ? in the body part of the HTTP request ? if yes in your code you seem to have a button, this will not work in the body of the http request.

Comment: This action is to send a rest request.You just need to add "X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE" to headers in this action.

Comment: Ah ...YES !!!! it works !! ...waw...thanks a lot for you help. I just kept what's on my screenshot and adapted according to your code. I removed "/group" in the URI , removed the "accept" header (those 2 were still showing errors) and added your  "X-HTTP-Method"  to the header as you said ....and that works :-) Thanks a lot for all your time !!!  (and sorry it took me so long to understand what you meant :-P )

Answer (score 0):

#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://xxxxxx.com"
$GroupName= "Sales Portal Members"
$NewGroupName ="Sales Managers"

#Connect PNP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)

#Update the Group Name
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $GroupName -Title $NewGroupName

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your answer.  Waw...ok... i admit you lost me :-) i'm not at that level.  what's there is PowerShell , isn't it ? would you please be able to transpose it the my HTTP request action ?  thanks a lot